# "Number guessing game" in Python

Tags: python, beginner, number-guessing-game

I am new to Python and I have tried to come up with a code for the number guessing game. But I am pretty sure this is not the right way to do it. I am able to get the right output, however, my code is pretty long. Any ideas on using a different logic or to reduce the code size would help.

I also would like to know how to code profile a python code for performance.

I am using IDLE and Python 3.+

```
import random

def main():
    while(True):
        inputchoice = input("Are you ready? Y/N : ")    
        if(inputchoice.strip() in ("y","Y","yes","Yes","YES","YEs","yeS","YeS","yEs","yES")):
            print("Ok. Lets begin")
            randomnumberguessinggame()
            break
        elif(inputchoice.strip() in ("no","No","NO","nO","n","N")):    
            print("Let me know when you are ready")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid Entry. Try again")

def randomnumberguessinggame():
    print("Get ready to start guessing")
    actualnumber = random.randrange(0,1000)
    #print("The number to be guessed is %d"%actualnumber)
    flag = True;
    while(flag):
        try:
            guessednumber = int(input("Enter your guess "))
            if(guessednumber > actualnumber):
                print("That was a wrong guess. Your guess is higher than my number")                
                while(True):
                    retry = input("Would you like to try again? Y/N : ")
                    if(retry.strip() in ("y","Y","yes","Yes","YES","YEs","yeS","YeS","yEs","yES")):
                        flag = True;
                        break
                    elif(retry.strip() in ("no","No","NO","nO","n","N")):
                        flag = False;
                        break
                    else:
                        print("Invalid Entry. Try again")
            elif(guessednumber < actualnumber):
                print("That was a wrong guess. Your guess is lower than my number")                
                while(True):
                    retry = input("Would you like to try again? Y/N : ")
                    if(retry.strip() in ("y","Y","yes","Yes","YES","YEs","yeS","YeS","yEs","yES")):
                        flag = True;
                        break
                    elif(retry.strip() in ("no","No","NO","nO","n","N")):
                        flag = False;
                        break
                    else:
                        print("Invalid Entry. Try again")
            else:
                print("You've got it right. Congratulations!!")
                flag = False;
        except ValueError:
            print("Your guess is invalid. Kindly guess again.")
            flag = True;

main()

print("Exiting the game...")
```

Comment: Small point: Why not replace the `inputchoice.strip() in ("y","Y","yes"," ...)` by just `inputchoice.strip().lower().startswith('y')`?

Comment: @JohnColeman Feel free to point that out in an answer. As for the reason? Beginners usually don't know such thing :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Advice 1**

I would not abuse the user with the question whether he wants to continue; just have a command (say, `quit`) for quitting the game while still guessing.

**Advice 2**

`randomnumberguessinggame`

The Python way is `random_number_guessing_game`.

**Advice 3**

You don't have to use parentheses in the branch and loop conditionals.

**Summa summarum**

I had this in mind:

```
import random


def main():
    actual_number = random.randrange(0, 1000)
    while True:
        guess = input("Enter your guess: ")

        if guess.strip().lower() == "quit":
            print("Bye!")
            return

        try:
            guess_number = int(guess)
        except ValueError:
            print(guess, "is not an integer!")
            continue

        if guess_number < actual_number:
            print("Your guess is too small.")
        elif guess_number > actual_number:
            print("Your guess is too large.")
        else:
            print(guess_number, "Excellent!")
            return

main()
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, remove all the semicolons, this is not Java or C#. Furthermore, You can extract a function that handles all the questions for confirmation. Next, why not consider every answer that is not a confirmation as a 'no' if you choose to ask that many times which I wouldn't.

I'd write it as follows:

```
import random

def play():
    print("Get ready to start guessing!")
    guessing_game(random.randrange(0, 1000))
    print("Congratulations!! Exiting the game...")

def guessing_game(number):
    try:
        guess = int(input("Enter your guess: "))
        if guess == number:
            return
        print(["Higher!", "Lower!"][guess > number])
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid!")
    guessing_game(number)

if __name__ == '__main__':  # this the proper way
    play()
```

Comment: @Graipher I wouldn't argue with the loop ;-) But since the OP asked to reduce code size (not to improve performance, memory footprint or readability), I went with the recursion.

Comment: Fair enough. Anyways, you already got my +1 for your first sentence.